# Mapping from multiple sources to destination using orika

Tags: java, spring-boot, orika

Is this possible in Orika. 2 source object and destination as instance property from both the class.

Example:

```
public class Destination {
private String loginId;
private Integer contactId;}

public class LoginDetails {
    private String loginId;
    private String clientId;
}

public class AlertEntityIdentity {
  private Integer contactId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mapperFactory.classMap(LoginDetails.class, Destination.class)
.byDefault().register();
mapperFactory.classMap(AlertEntityIdentity.class, Destination.class)
.byDefault().register();
```

Assume you have `loginDetails` and `alertEntityIdentity`.

```
Destination destination = mapperFacade.map(loginDetails, Destination.class);
mapperFacade.map(alertEntityIdentity, destination);// this will update contactId in destination
```